# i have a problem in my wallet

Tags: ether

where can I find out where I have created a wallet ?
i opened through a website a wallet for eth but i forgot the website i opened the wallet through.
Im mining on Nanopool website , here is the wallets address that im mining in:
https://eth.nanopool.org/account/0x0d505fe7aac5eefb5591c692cfdc77e4f0069041
i have in this wallet 3.56 ETH

How can i know in through which website i have opened the wallet? 
i didnt find anything in my history.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see on EtherScan, the address [0x0d505fe7aac5eefb5591c692cfdc77e4f0069041](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0d505fe7aac5eefb5591c692cfdc77e4f0069041) has 3.56 ETH, indeed. I am not familiar with Nanopool's procedures, but you should be able to:

1. Withdraw your funds from their centralised web app, if that's an account controlled by them.
2. If you have a private key, log in to [myetherwallet.com](https://myetherwallet.com) (always make sure you see the green lock and the company name as in the image below) and you get access to your funds there.

[image]

As a side note, I'd strongly recommend reading about [Ethereum addresses](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-Ethereum-contract-address) and how to keep your private keys secure.